# How to disply a combination of text and looped vars in a foreach statement

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

The following statement is erring in my MVC razor view.

```
 @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
                {
                    <li><a href="#">Add user</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">@user.FirstName @user.LastName 
                        if(user.FirstName != "")
                        { 
                        @(@user.UserName)
                        }else{ 
                        @user.UserName
                        }
                        </a></li>
                }
```

I cannot seem to figure out the razor to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are looking for `@if` instead of `if` because starting HTML tag switches context from "code" to HTML and you need to switch it back to "code".

```
@foreach(...
{
<span>...
  @if(...) 
  {
     <text>@user.UserName</text>
  }
</span>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was simple! Doh.